# Assigning one scope variable to another becomes by reference

Tags: angularjs

This is way out there, even for me.

When I run this line of code:

```
$scope.groupNameHold = $scope.details.gameDetails.groups[key].name;
```

Any changes to $scope.groupNameHold also change the value of the gameDetails variable. Why? It doesn't make any sense to me.

`name` is a string, not an object.

Comment: Is name an object or a string? Objects are by reference

Comment: `name` is a string. Updating question for clarity, thanks.

Comment: Please provide a plunkr. It's working as expected when I ran your posted code: [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/odq3S0VhtHN2ugVttJqS?p=preview)

Comment: I'll have to figure out how to replicate this in Plunkr. The data that populates `name` comes from an API.

Comment: Made a plunkr, can't replicate. Guess I gotta figure out what's different now...

Comment: Are you simply asking why this happens, or do you need a solution? I had the same issue at some point, so I used angular.copy(source, [destination]), problem solved.